# Import UTF-8 text file (& input in data frame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, utf-8

Here is an example output for the input txt file.

> PT    AU  BA  CA  GP  RI
>   J   Garcia-Perez, Guillermo; Rossi, Matteo A. C.; Maniscalco, Sabrina               Rossi, Matteo/E-4964-2015   Rossi, Matteo/0000-0003-4665-9284; Garcia-Perez, Guillermo/0000-0002-9006-060X          IBM Q Experience as a versatile experimental testbed for simulating open quantum systems                                NPJ QUANTUM INFORMATION             6   1                   1   10.1038/s41534-019-0235-y               DEC 2020

Currently I use the following code:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('savedrecs-2.txt')
df.head()
```

However, the results are not split according to the columns provided in the utf-8 text file.

Current Output:

```
0
0   PT\tAU\tBA\tCA\tGP\tRI\tOI\tBE\tZ2\tTI\tX1\tY...
1   J\tGarcia-Perez, Guillermo; Rossi, Matteo A. C...
2   J\tScholes, Colin A.; Kentish, Sandra E.; Qade...
3   J\tVillain-Gambier, M.; Courbalay, M.; Klem, A...
4   J\tShahmahdi, Najmeh; Dehghanzadeh, Reza; Asla...
```

Expected Output (example)

```
PT            AU    BA  CA  GP  RI
Garcia-Perez  xy    xy  xy  xy  xy
Guillermo     xy    xy  xy  xy  xy
```

Comment: So how _are_ the columns organized? Without seeing an excerpt of the file contents it is difficult to say what goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, the first values indicate the columns: 'PT AU BA CA GP RI'; the above is an extract from the actual file.

Comment: Ok, so that is the input - that looks like it's not in fixed width format. Your columns must have the same width to be autodetected (thus fwf for "fixed width format").

Comment: Thank you, question is now updated - any suggestions to this problem?

Comment: I updated the comment - please check if that's the problem. You can check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Comment: maybe you should `read_csv( ..., sep="\t")` ?

Comment: @furas - I thought about that, too, but it doesn't seem to match the expected outcome, or the input for that matter...

Answer (score 1):

The following code appears to return the expected result.

```
filename = 'savedrecs-8.txt'

doc = codecs.open(filename,'rU','UTF-8')
df = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='\t')
```